# Accessing a LaTeX code from comments to incorporate it in the answer

Tags: support, mathjax

Suppose you wrote an answer, and people ask in the comments for details: so you answer the details in form of comments, but then, when you no longer can edit them, you would like your comments to be part now of your answer.

- Is there a way to do that, without having to write the LaTeX again?
- I mean, I'm not asking for being able to edit the comments, but for every user to be able to extract the code of her/his own comments.

Comment: +1, I was thinking today to ask the same question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the LaTeX. Click `Show Math As`>`TeX Commands`

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. So it helps a lot. (I guess, it's impossible to extract the whole comment, though.  Nevermind.)